# A machine produces memory sticks of varying lengths...

Tags: probability, statistics

Full question:

A machine produces memory sticks of varying lengths, distributed uniformly between 2 and 12 mm. Memory sticks longer than 10 mm do not meet the design criterion and must be scrapped.

A) Calculate the proportion of memory sticks that will be scrapped.

My answer: There are 2 to 12mm sticks so 10 different memory sticks total. Longer than 10 must be scrapped so 2 out of 10 or 1/5 must be scrapped.

B) Simulate 50 memory stick lengths and obtain a histogram of the simulated values. Calculate the simulated mean and variance.

I don't know how to approach this problem.

Please check my answer to part A, and any help with part B is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have a feeling that they meant _continuous_ uniform, not discrete uniform. Also, for part b) I'm assuming they mean for you to use a computer.

Comment: As probablyme says for part B) we may assume you are supposed to use a computer. If so what tool are you supposed to use, Matlab, R, .. ? Or are you supposed to do a hand or spreadsheet simulation (just possible with a sample size of 50) ?

Comment: Did the answer help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ad A)**

Your are right. There are 10 intervals between 2 and 12, if the interval length is 1.

**Ad B)**
You can use excel or a similar program. I agree to a comment that the numbers between 2 and 12 haven´t to be integers. So the formula is

$\texttt{=Rand()*(12-2)+2}$

$\texttt{=Rand()}$ produces random numbers in the interval $[0,1)$

The results have to be classified. If the result is $4.6432$, then this number is in the in the interval $[ 4,5)$.

After you have insert this formula in a cell this formula can be copied 49 times. For this purpose you can use the [fill handle](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/7.4). With the result you can make a histogram. As I said, I would recommend to use an interval width of $1$.